# How to listen to one client at a time in Java using server socket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class MultiServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSock=new ServerSocket(3000);
        //server socket creation

        System.out.println("waiting for client.........");
          
        Socket socket=serverSock.accept();

        System.out.println("client connected ");

        BufferedReader keyRead=new BufferedReader(new 

        inputStreamReader(System.in));
        OutputStream ostream=socket.getOutputStream();//sending to client
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(ostream,true);
        InputStream istream=socket.getInputStream();//receiving from server (istream object)
        BufferedReader receiveRead=new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(istream));
        String receiveMessage,sendMessage;
        while(true)
        {
            if((receiveMessage=receiveRead.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println("client:>"+ receiveMessage);
            }
 
            sendMessage=keyRead.readLine();
            pw.println(sendMessage);
            System.out.flush();//flush the Stream
            if(sendMessage.equals("bye"))
            {
                break;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

This code is to connect a client at a time, but I want to display a message saying that the server is busy if other client attempts to chat with the same server. That message should respond on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to display a message that the server is busy if other client attempts to chat with the same server. that message should respond on both the side

Basically impossible. The `listen()` backlog queue will cause a subsequent client's connection attempt to complete and be queued for the next `accept()` call by the server. There is nothing you can do about this short of closing the listening socket until you're ready to accept the next client, which introduces all kinds of timing constraints.

You could set a flag while you have a client and check it when you accept another one, and send him the message and disconnect him, but I fail to see the point.

> that message should respond on both sides

What both sides? The side of the new client and who else?

Strange requirement. How can a chat server only want one client? Who is he chatting to?

Comment: thanks for reply.... let me go in detail of the requirement.. will revert back to you once clear